# FirebasePaginator is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I'm using a library developed by Chris Esplin ([firebase-paginator](https://github.com/deltaepsilon/firebase-paginator)) but i get FirebasePaginator is not a constructor when i try to use it. I'm actually developing a PWA in Vue.js 2.0, the script where this is getting called it's in ***app-name/src/store/index.js*** which is the main file for manage vuex states, mutations, actions and getters.

```
  var FirebasePaginator = require('firebase-paginator')
  var options = {
    pageSize: 20,
    finite: true,
    auth: 'SomeAuthToken',
    retainLastPage: false
  }
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('track')
  var paginator = new FirebasePaginator(ref, options)
  var collection = null
  paginator.once('value')
    .then(() => {
      collection = paginator.collection
      console.log(paginator, collection)
    })
```

I've tried with a custom paginator that found googling, i adapted to eslint rules and i get the same constructor error when i make the call with ***new***

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Vue.js, but I only ever designed FirebasePaginator to work with script tags for the browser or require calls for Node.js. The "not a constructor" error indicates that the library wasn't imported correctly.

Try adding `/node_modules/firebase-paginator/firebase-paginator.js` to the page in a script tag. I'm sure there's a way to get `require('firebase-paginator')` to work with require statements in the browser, but I don't use them that way myself, so if you figure it out, I'd welcome a pull request.

Also, make sure that you don't use your legacy admin auth token in the browser. I think the REST API will work with auth tokens from your authenticated user, but I haven't played with that feature in a while, so I'm uncertain. Infinite pagination may be easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Chris, i didn't expected from you. Unfortunately the Vue frameworks uses components and adding a script tag directly isn't posible, i made some workarounds to get that done but the result is the same. The only thing that can make it work will be to create a class that adapts to Vue plugins requirements, that will take more development but should work using your pagination logic. PS: i'm a fan n.n